# How do add row striping CSS classes in Views?

Tags: views

I'm sure that on older versions of Drupal (6 or 7?) Views that showed as tables automatically had odd/even striping background colours.

Is there a UI option for this in D8/9?

I've done it in code like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK(): views_view_table.
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_table(&$variables) {
  // Add zebra striping classes to the view rows.
  foreach ($variables['rows'] as $index => &$row) {
    $row['attributes']->addClass($index % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd');
  }
}
```

and it turns out that Bartik theme has 'even' and 'odd' CSS that work fine.

But is there a simpler way?